# Minimum Number of operations needed to break a number into numbers less than a target

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have two numbers $m$ and $n$, $m > n$. For a single operation, we are allowed to split $m$ into the sum of two smaller numbers each of which is greater or equal to one. We want to find the minimum number of operations to break $m$ down so that each component is less than or equal to $n$. The answer is the largest integer less than or equal to $\frac{m-1}{n}$.

For example, for $m = 4, n = 2$ you just need one operation to break $4$ into $2$ and $2$.

My thinking is that in the end the nicest situation is that you want each component to be at least $n$, so it is natural to look at $\frac{m}{n}$, but then you will have to use $\frac{m}{n} - 1$ operations because for each new component you need one operation and you originally start with one component. But this is certainly not correct if you try $m = 5, n = 2$.

Comment: are you sure that the numbers should be greater than one (i.e. at least 2, assuming only integers are allowed)? because then for $n=2$ all the components must be equal to 2 and the task isn't even possible for $m=5$

Comment: What exactly did you mean with "the answer is $\frac{m-1}{n}$. That is not always an integer...

Comment: I have updated the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any number $m$ can be  split up into into Int$(\frac{m}{n})$ copies of $n$ plus a non-negative remainder less than $n$, where Int$(x)$ represents the integer part of $x$.
This takes Int$(\frac{m}{n})$ operations unless the remainder is zero when one fewer operation is required.

Note that the restriction "each of which is greater than one" has to be removed. Otherwise you will not always be able to get to numbers less than or equal to $n$.

Comment: Is it obvious that this is the minimum number of operations?

Comment: An expression of $m$ as a sum of numbers with $k$ addition signs (and therefore $k+1$ numbers), will have required $k$ operations. Each of the numbers has to be at most $n$ and so $m\le n(k+1)$.